# How can I reduce the frequency of "synchronizing block information" phases in CrashPlan PROe?

Tags: windows-7, backup, crashplan

How can I reduce the frequency of "synchronizing block information" phases in CrashPlan PROe? It typically takes hours to complete, seems to occur every two days or so, and in the meantime files don't get backed up.

I use CrashPlan PROe 3.7.0 with Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Example:

[image]

To make matters worse, it is followed by a scan:

[image]

---

My settings:

[image]

My advanced settings (grayed out, it seems that I cannot change them):

[image]

The following setting seems interesting but is grayed out  as well:

[image]

Comment: Frank - I went ahead and added an answer summing up all we've been going over in comments. When you get a chance, let me know if you feel this covers all the discussed topics, options, and so on in the comments; I went ahead and cleaned those up so feel free to do the same with yours. I felt froggy so I jumped... Ribbbitt!!

Comment: @PIMP_JUICE_IT awesome, thanks :) I'll keep you posted.

Comment: @Homey_D_Clown_IT eventually the admin unlocked the "verify selection every", it did the trick. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Potential Considerations

- The [Administration Guide Advanced Settings
  section](https://support.code42.com/Administrator/3/Administration_Console_Reference/Device_Backup_Reference#Advanced_Settings)
  indicates that if you set the [**Data
  de-duplication**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_deduplication)
  option value to **Full** this may help identify duplicate data to
  potentially help speed up the process.
- From this same [admin
  guide](https://support.code42.com/Administrator/3/Administration_Console_Reference/Device_Backup_Reference#Advanced_Settings),
  it's indicated that if you set the **Compression** option value to
  **On**, this too may be helpful in speeding up the process due to less bandwidth and less disk I/O being used.
- The [Device Backup Reference
  guide](https://support.code42.com/Administrator/3/Administration_Console_Reference/Device_Backup_Reference#General)
  indicates that in **General** you can set the **Backup will run**
  option to a value of **Always** so the backup always runs and it may
  only backup the changed data since the last backup, so consider
  testing and researching this further for performance benefits.
- The [Using Backup Sets admin
  guide](https://support.code42.com/Administrator/3/Configuring/Using_Backup_Sets)
  indicates you may want to have only one default
  **Backup Sets** and not more than one set to ensure that you are always backing up to the same destination as frequently as you have scheduled and configured per all your settings. Have a look at [Specifying Version Settings](https://support.code42.com/CrashPlan/4/Configuring/Specifying_Version_Settings) for further clarification on applicable options as well.

---

### If You Cannot Change These Settings

If you determine that these options are *grayed out, not changeable, or enforced at another level* for the way this software is configured and setup in your environment you'll want to ***see where else these changes may need to be made to be effective on your client workstation***.

According to the same [admin guide](https://support.code42.com/Administrator/3/Administration_Console_Reference/Device_Backup_Reference#Advanced_Settings) in **Advanced Settings**, you will see there is an option with a little **lock** symbol [image] indicating whether or not these settings are **lock**ed and *preventing users from changing this value from their personal settings*.

Consider the following options but don't limit to yourself them only:

- See if there's a setting in the client interface to **unlock** these so the changes can be changed
- Check a higher level in your configuration setup with this software to see if these settings can only be changed (**unlocked**) from a server policy or configuration file—***check with your server or local PC admin if this is not you***.
- If you have support with this software, reach out to [them] the vendor for support to assist in resolving the issue.

> ### <sub>Advanced Settings</sub>
>
> <sub>**Data de-duplication**</sub>
>
> - <sub>**Description:** *Controls data de-duplication rate.*</sub>
> - <sub>**Full -** *Every effort is made to identify duplicate data. While being 100% effective, it requires a great deal of CPU power. You're
>     sacrificing CPU and speed to save bandwidth and disk at destination.*</sub>
>
> <sub>**Compression**</sub>
>
> - <sub>**Description:** *Controls how CrashPlan service compresses your backup. Compressed backups use less bandwidth and less disk space.
>
>     Compression does consume some CPU, but not enough to offset overhead
>
>     due to maxing out your bandwidth or I / O. Because you generally have 
>     more CPU available than bandwidth or disk I / O, we do not recommend
>
>     turning off compression.*</sub>
> - <sub>**On -** *All files are compressed.*</sub>
>
> <sub>**Lock**</sub>
>
> - <sub>**Descripton:** *Locks this setting to prevent users from changing it in their personal settings.*</sub>
>
> <sub><sub>[source](https://support.code42.com/Administrator/3/Administration_Console_Reference/Device_Backup_Reference#Advanced_Settings)</sub></sub>
>
> ---
>
> ### <sub>General</sub>
>
> <sub>**Backup Sets**</sub>
>
> - <sub>**Description:** *Displays [Backup Sets](https://support.code42.com/Administrator/3/Configuring/Using_Backup_Sets)
>     sheet in which you can create and configure backup sets.*</sub>
>
> <sub>**Backup will run**</sub>
>
> - <sub>**Description:** *Indicates whether backups are always running or running only at specific times.*</sub>
>
> <sub><sub>[source](https://support.code42.com/Administrator/3/Administration_Console_Reference/Device_Backup_Reference#General)</sub></sub>
>
> ---
>
> ### <sub>Backup Frequency</sub>
>
> <sub>*CrashPlan backs up new changes to files as often as your
>   [Backup Frequency](https://support.code42.com/CrashPlan/4/CrashPlan_App_Reference/Backup_Settings_Reference)
>   settings allow. CrashPlan watches the filesystem in    real-time
>   (unless that feature is turned off), and when a file    changes it
>   schedules the next backup of that file based on the    frequency
>   settings (i.e. if the backup frequency is set to the    default 15
>   minutes, once a file changes CrashPlan will schedule a    backup to
>   happen 15 minutes later).*</sub>
>
> <sub><sub>[source](https://support.code42.com/CrashPlan/4/Configuring/Specifying_Version_Settings)</sub></sub>

---

### References

- [**Advanced Settings - Device Backup Reference**](https://support.code42.com/Administrator/3/Administration_Console_Reference/Device_Backup_Reference#Advanced_Settings)
- [**General - Device Backup Reference**](https://support.code42.com/Administrator/3/Administration_Console_Reference/Device_Backup_Reference#General)
- [**Using Backup Sets**](https://support.code42.com/Administrator/3/Configuring/Using_Backup_Sets)
- [**Specifying Version Settings**](https://support.code42.com/CrashPlan/4/Configuring/Specifying_Version_Settings)
- [**Backup Settings Reference**](https://support.code42.com/CrashPlan/4/CrashPlan_App_Reference/Backup_Settings_Reference)

---

### Guide Screen Shots

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Recommend you preface your detailed configuration notes with a general statement about block sync in Crashplan. My understanding is that it is quite normal for Crashplan to inexplicitly and unexpectedly spend hours and hours on this task.

Comment: @JohnC Please explain what you suggest regarding this and. . . **" My understanding is that it is quite normal for Crashplan to inexplicitly and unexpectedly spend hours and hours on this task"**?. I'm not sure what you're asking me to add to my answer.

Comment: Suggest you open your answer by stating whether it is practical to do as the OP asks, "to reduce the frequency" and the duration too, and by how much relatively speaking, to set expectations. Eg from "hours" to what? Various blogs that I've read state that it is standard for Crashplan to frequently sync blocks and spend a long time doing it. Hence the OP request is perhaps not achievable. That is my experience too. I'm not complaining about your answer, just curious to learn from your experience.